# Jumping Animation: First animation duration doesn't work. IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an animation that, when a button is pressed, is supposed to jump up, then float back down. I use to animations one to make it float up, the second to make it come down. No matter what I do the first animation doesn't float, it just teleports to the top, and the second does exactly what it should.

This is what I have:

```
//This animation does not respond to its duration.
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect f = imageView.frame;
                     f.origin.y -= 40;
                     imView.frame = f;
                 }
                 completion:nil];

[UIView animateWithDuration:.7 delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect f = imageView.frame;
                     f.origin.y += 40;
                     imView.frame = f;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

another problem I have it that I want to change the image through out the animation but it always ends up starting with the image I declare last. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second animation overwrites the first animation because it doesnt have a delay.  Try starting the second animation from the first animation's completion block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect f = imageView.frame;
                     f.origin.y -= 40;
                     imView.frame = f;
                 }
                 completion:^{
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:.7 delay:0.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                      animations:^{
                                         CGRect f = imageView.frame;
                                         f.origin.y += 40;
                                         imView.frame = f;
                                      }
                                      completion:nil];
                 }];
```

Comment: I could make an animation without the "delay: options:" part but that still doesn't work. What do you men in the completion block? like where "completion:nil" is? Im new to IOS and could use some more explanation.

Comment: did you see the edit? I didn't want to take credit for the answer as rob posted it first

Comment: Nested block is not that comfortable for me to read. Two is OK. What about more like 5 or 10? Is there alternative way around?

Comment: @Philip007 Yes but you should post a new question for that.